# How to correctly use an integral to model the density?

Tags: integration, statistics, mathematical-modeling, density-function

> I have a density function $p_X(x)$ of an image $X \in \mathbb{R}^2$ over a set of points $x_i \in X$. If two points $x_i$ and $x_j$ are within a fixed distance of $\epsilon$ from each other, I want to connect them with an edge. We can find the euclidean distance of every two values BUT this is too slow so i want to create a continuous model to speed it up.

Firstly, define the density as

$$\rho_0 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N\delta(X - x_i).$$

Convolve it with a scaled Gaussian Kernel, to get

$$\rho_X = \psi \circledast \rho_0 = \frac{1}{2N\epsilon^2 \pi} \sum_{i=1}^N e^{-\frac{(X-x_i)^2}{2\epsilon^2}}$$

My idea is then to **integrate $p_X$ over a ball of size $\epsilon$ and centered at the point $x_i$,** i.e. the probability $x_j$ is a distance of $\epsilon$ from $x_i$:

$$ \int_{D(\epsilon,x_i)} p_X dX=  \frac{1}{2N\pi \epsilon^2} \int_{D(\epsilon,x_i)} \sum_{i=1}^N e^{-\frac{(x_1 - x_i)^2 + (x_2 - x_i)^2}{2\epsilon^2}} dx_1dx_2 \approx 0.39$$

If, $ \int_D p_X \ge C\epsilon^2$, then we join an edge between $x_i$ and any $x_j$ in this ball, since the probability they are close is high enough.

However, the result gives a **constant** so it would always be the same and hence useless to model. Should I integrate a different region and include $x_j$ somehow? But, say if I integrate each $x_i$ at a ball of size $x_j$, I do **NOT** want to compute the distance between every $x_i$ and $x_j$ as it defeats the purpose of why I'm doing this!

Comment: Are you trying to estimate the probability of an edge forming between two points? And what exactly is the distribution of $p_X$. You seem to have taken a normal distribution centered at x_i.

Comment: The probability they are sufficiently close together, so therefore an edge should be formed. I took the density of the sum of points $\rho = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N\delta(X - x_i)$ and convolved it with a Gaussian kernel. The summation goes away during calculations. @Yadeses

Comment: Ah, okay. Wait, should the integral not read $\frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon} \int_{D(\epsilon, x_i)} e^{-\frac{(X - x_j)^2}{2\epsilon^2}} dx_1 dx_2$. So currently, you have a density centered at $x_i$ and integrate a disk around $x_i$. However, it seems like you want to have a density centered at $x_j$ and then integrate a disk around $x_i$. Then you cannot convert to polar coordinates any more and your integral will depend on $x_i$ and $x_j$.

Comment: @Yadeses Yeah sort of but due to scale preserving it should have $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$. If I integrated a ball of size $x_j$, then I would need to find the euclidean distance of each $x_i$ and $x_j$ though, which defeats the purpose of what I want to do. I could already do that, but it's too slow, so I want to use a method with a density function!

Comment: I assume this has to do with some computations. In that case, you could sort the coordinates in one direction and then use a sliding window of size epsilon. That should significantly reduce computation time. I do not really envision any methods based on this density kernel being faster than that.

Comment: @Yadeses Yes i've done this approach but I also wanted to test this idea to see if it works and how it compares!